# document.getElementById and using id name

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following in HTML code:

```
<section id="main-content">
    <header>
        <h1 id="page-title">Why Are There No Arab Democracies?</h1>
    </header>
```

To retrieve the contents of `page-title`, I've tried to use, among others, the following:

`document.getElementById("page-title")[0].InnerText`

`document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].getElementById("page-title")[0].InnerText`

Each time I get an error.

Comment: `)[0].InnerText` to `).InnerText`.... `getElementById` returns the element not any collection.

Comment: Examining the text of the error and doing a web search for it will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Should be `innerText` not `InnerText`. [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext)

Comment: @AndyG It should actually be `textContent`. `innerText` is a non-standard property introduced by, guess what? the infamous Internet Explorer.

Comment: There is a detailed discussion of the two here [The poor, misunderstood innerText](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/), I was just pointing out the error in capitalization ;)

Comment: In my programming language I can use either  innerText or InnerText. Each of them works fine.

Comment: @AndyG That article 'has nailed it'.

Comment: @Vohuman Run this code in AutoHotKey and you will know that either innerText and InnerText works. When you get back don't forget to write that you were wrong and your comment was very silly.

Comment: @Vohuman I see you aren't able to say that you were wrong. Poor you. You have been nailed.

Comment: Run this code in AHK and check if it works. That's the thing. In my programming language = In a language I use. It was obvious for everyone but you. I don't think you are a native speaker of English, perhaps that the reason.

Comment: It seems that you won't discuss the issue of AutoHotKey, a programming language in which either of the spellings is correct. This was the issue here. I don't think I will reply to any of your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0]` is used when you are grabbing multiple elements & you want to choose the first element from the list.

Eg: If your page has multiple `<p>` and you do a `getElementByTagName('p')` then you need to use `[0]` to access first element in the list of all captured elements.

```
<p>Hello</p><p>hi</p>
```

then

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML); ## this alerts "Hello"
```

---

Answer to your question:

```js
alert(document.getElementById('page-title').innerHTML);
```

```html
<section id="main-content">

  <header>
    <h1 id="page-title">Why Are There No Arab Democracies?</h1>

  </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've marked this an an accepted answer since it is the most detailed.

Comment: Good to know it helped.

Comment: @menteith you are are supposed to click on the tick to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById();` like this instead. You also should use `.textContent` to find the text of the element.

The reason you do not have to use `[0]` when finding elements by id is because `getElementById` returns one element because there should only be one element in your HTML with a named id.

```js
alert(document.getElementById("page-title").textContent);
```

```html
<section id="main-content">
  <header>
    <h1 id="page-title">Why Are There No Arab Democracies?</h1>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("page-title").innerText
```

you're only grabbing one element, so no need for the `[0]`